# sbt is using "default" project instead of creating a new one

Tags: java, scala, configuration, build, sbt

I've just installed sbt on my Windows Vista machine, following the guide on github wiki, using a sbt.bat script containing

```
set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
     -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar "%SCRIPT_DIR%sbt-launch.jar" %*
```

When I run `sbt` in an empty directory, I get

```
L:\foo>sbt

L:\foo>set SCRIPT_DIR=L:\lib\sbt\

L:\foo>java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar "L:\lib\sbt\sbt-launch.jar"
[info] Set current project to default-058262 (in build file:/L:/foo/)
>
```

instead of expected prompt to create a new project. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Specify name of the project in build file, `default-058262` just a random name replacement for unnamed projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In contrast with SBT 0.7, SBT 0.10+ does not prompt you for project creation, but assumes some default configuration and deploy its own working directories.

If you want to provide you settings, you must add an `build.sbt` file or a full configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Add the np plugin. This replaces the previous functionality.
https://github.com/softprops/np